# PHP code working locally but not on Azure

Tags: php, azure, sparkpost

I've implemented a mail delivery service using SparkPost for a website. The code looks like this:

```
require '/vendor/autoload.php';

use SparkPost\SparkPost; use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use Ivory\HttpAdapter\Guzzle6HttpAdapter;
$httpAdapter = new Guzzle6HttpAdapter(new Client());
$sparky = new SparkPost($httpAdapter, ['key'=>'...']);
[...]
[...]
$results = $sparky->transmission->send($mailarray);
```

It works just fine locally on WampServer, however when I deploy it to Azure it does not. I don't have access to Azure logs, but I managed to narrow down the problem to one line:

```
$sparky = new SparkPost($httpAdapter, ['key'=>'...']);
```

I simply get a 500 error without any other explanation. The weird thing is when I wrap it around a try/catch, I still don't get anything other than a blank screen and a 500 on the console. I suspect it has to do something with /autoload.php not being able to load something.

Any thoughts?

Comment: check the error log for details about the 500. not everything in php can be try/catched, e.g. fatal parse errors.

Comment: There is a possibility of white spaces in the PHP that you cannot see or something above is causing it / on a different page. Are you in a while loop anywhere that is an infinite loop?

Comment: check your uppercase in your require path (and other place). local/dev/prod can be sensitive/insensitive to the casse

Comment: Using the .user.ini method to see errors on server, I found this as the cause, which makes it even harder for me to understand: **Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context in D:\home\site\wwwroot\assets\vendor\sparkpost\php-sparkpost\lib\SparkPost\SparkPost.php on line 118**

Comment: Turns out the Azure instance I'm deploying to uses PHP 5.4 while SparkPost library needs PHP 5.5 or higher to run. That's probably the root cause.

Comment: @ShaahinSh Post that as an answer and select that as the correct answer if you think that's what caused it.

Comment: @C.Liddell  will do so once I verify -- I'm currently waiting on the entity managing Azure instance to change the running PHP version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According the requirement of SparkPost lib on Github repo at https://github.com/SparkPost/php-sparkpost/blob/master/composer.json#L18, it need PHP version higher than `5.5`. So you can modify the PHP version of your Azure Web Apps, please refer to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-php-configure/#how-to-change-the-built-in-php-version for detail steps.

Comment: I had suggested PHP version as the cause on the comments as well. I finally verified that was the cause so I'm marking your response as the correct answer.